# There are multiple navigations in entity type 'Messages' which are pointing to same set of properties - 'MessageFrom' using ForeignKeyAttribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table Messages and a table apartments . 
Messages have MessageFrom related To apartmentId and MessageTo which is  also related to apartment id . 
i implement my code like always using entity framework core . but things doesn't seems right . 
Here is my code :

1 - Application DbContext

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Messages>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.MessageId);
                entity.Property(e => e.DateOfMessage).HasColumnType("DateTime");
                entity.Property(e => e.Message).HasColumnType("nvarchar(300)").HasMaxLength(300);
                entity.Property(e => e.IsRed).HasColumnName("IsRed").HasColumnType("bit");
                entity.Property(e => e.MessageTo).HasColumnType("int");
                entity.HasOne(e => e.Apartment).WithMany(x => x.Messages).HasForeignKey(e => e.MessageFrom).HasConstraintName("FK_MessageFrom_Apartment");
                entity.HasOne(e => e.Apartment).WithMany(x => x.Messages).HasForeignKey(e => e.MessageTo).HasConstraintName("FK_MessageTo_Apartment");

        });
```

2 - Model Class :

```
  public class Messages
    {

        public int MessageId { get; set; }





        public int ?MessageFrom { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MessageFrom")]
        public Apartment Apartment { get; set; }


        public int ?MessageTo { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MessageTo")]
        public Apartment apartment { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DateOfMessage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public bool IsRed { get; set; }

    }
```

3 - the problem is:
**There are multiple navigations in entity type 'Messages' which are pointing to same set of properties - 'MessageFrom' using ForeignKeyAttribute**

4- sometimes it gives : 
Invalid column name 'ApartmentId'.' while i dont have apartmentId at all in model messages

Comment: Have you tried renaming the two apartment keys to something like `ApartmentFrom` and `ApartmentTo`? In your Fluent API code, you're referencing the same `Apartment` property twice

Comment: @Versailles yes i did

Answer (score 0):

This code here:

```
            entity.HasOne(e => e.Apartment).WithMany(x => x.Messages).HasForeignKey(e => e.MessageFrom).HasConstraintName("FK_MessageFrom_Apartment");
            entity.HasOne(e => e.Apartment).WithMany(x => x.Messages).HasForeignKey(e => e.MessageTo).HasConstraintName("FK_MessageTo_Apartment");
```

References the same navigation property. Rename + Update References will keep this code broken.

```
    public int ?MessageFrom { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MessageFrom")]
    public virtual Apartment ApartmentFrom { get; set; }


    public int ?MessageTo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MessageTo")]
    public virtual Apartment ApartmentTo { get; set; }
```

With these attributed members you do not need/want the duplication with the modelBuilder, use one or the other. ColumnType and such can also be declared via attributes. My guess is EF is getting confused between the attributes and the modelBuilder configuration.

I would also not recommend differentiating members by case alone as I can pretty much guarantee this will lead to bugs in your code from confusion around the two. :)